# Extract useful information from a table to predict real scenarios

Tags: r, prediction

let's say I am the director of a delivery company and I'd like to address on which conditions my products reach the receivers in good quality (e.g. not broken, still well enveloped, etc..).

```
Product operator1   operator2   operator3   operator4   weather day quality
product1    x   0   0   x   sun mon x
product2    0   x   0   0   grey    tue 0
product3    x   x   x   x   grey    mon x
product4    0   x   0   0   cloudy  fri 0
product5    0   0   x   x   grey    sat 0
product6    x   x   0   0   grey    wed x
product7    x   0   0   x   cloudy  wed 0
product8    0   0   x   x   grey    wed x
product9    x   0   0   0   grey    mon 0
product10   0   0   x   0   cloudy  tue x
```

So I've this (proxy) table and I'd like to extract such kind of information in any combination and number of variables for example:

```
Operator1 = x
Operator2 = x
Operator3 = x
Operator4 = x
Weather = sunny
Day = mon
Operator1 = x + Operator2 = x
Operator1 = x + weather = sunny
etc..
```

to test when ratio of the (n. of products in good quality)/(n. of products filtered on specific variable values) meet a ratio of let's say > 0.8. In this way I'd determine what are the best conditions to deliver my products.
I understand is a complex question but I hope there's somebody that knows some way or some specific (preferably R) packages that can address this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible to do what you want, and I'll give you an example here of how it can be achieved, but it looks as though you could do with reading a good primer on R to understand the different data types and basic concepts of data manipulation.

First, I'll load a copy of your data into R as a data frame:

```r
data.frame(Product = paste0("product", 1:10),
           operator1 = unlist(strsplit("x0x00xx0x0", "")),
           operator2 = unlist(strsplit("0xxx0x0000", "")),
           operator3 = unlist(strsplit("00x0x00x0x", "")),
           operator4 = unlist(strsplit("x0x0x0xx00", "")),
           weather   = c("sun", "grey", "grey", "cloudy", "grey", 
                         "grey", "cloudy", "grey", "grey", "grey"),
           day       = c("mon", "tue", "mon", "fri", "sat", 
                         "wed", "wed", "wed", "mon", "tue"),
           quality = unlist(strsplit("x0x00x0x0x", ""))) -> deliveries
```

To show this is the same as your data:

```r
> deliveries
     Product operator1 operator2 operator3 operator4 weather day quality
1   product1         x         0         0         x     sun mon       x
2   product2         0         x         0         0    grey tue       0
3   product3         x         x         x         x    grey mon       x
4   product4         0         x         0         0  cloudy fri       0
5   product5         0         0         x         x    grey sat       0
6   product6         x         x         0         0    grey wed       x
7   product7         x         0         0         x  cloudy wed       0
8   product8         0         0         x         x    grey wed       x
9   product9         x         0         0         0    grey mon       0
10 product10         0         0         x         0    grey tue       x
```

Now, we need to make your table into a format that can be processed properly. Columns of 0's and x's won't be understood by R as you intend, so you need to convert these into either TRUE/FALSE values, or 0/1 values. We can do this with some help from the `dplyr` package, which is part of the `tidyverse`:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

deliveries %<>% transmute(Product = Product,
                          operator1 = as.numeric(operator1 == "x"),
                          operator2 = as.numeric(operator2 == "x"),
                          operator3 = as.numeric(operator3 == "x"),
                          operator4 = as.numeric(operator4 == "x"),
                          weather = weather,
                          day = day,
                          quality   = as.numeric(quality == "x"))
```

Now your data looks like this:

```r
     Product operator1 operator2 operator3 operator4 weather day quality
1   product1         1         0         0         1     sun mon       1
2   product2         0         1         0         0    grey tue       0
3   product3         1         1         1         1    grey mon       1
4   product4         0         1         0         0  cloudy fri       0
5   product5         0         0         1         1    grey sat       0
6   product6         1         1         0         0    grey wed       1
7   product7         1         0         0         1  cloudy wed       0
8   product8         0         0         1         1    grey wed       1
9   product9         1         0         0         0    grey mon       0
10 product10         0         0         1         0    grey tue       1
```

Now you can summarise the proportions for any combination you choose by putting the column names in the group_by function. In this case, let's do operator1, day and weather:

```r
deliveries %>% 
  group_by(operator1, day, weather) %>% 
  summarise(quality = paste0(mean(quality) * 100, "%"))
```

Which hopefully gives the kind of result you are looking for, with the proportion of quality deliveries shown for each combination of variables.

```r
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   operator1, day [?]
  operator1 day   weather quality
      <dbl> <fct> <fct>   <chr>  
1         0 fri   cloudy  0%     
2         0 sat   grey    0%     
3         0 tue   grey    50%    
4         0 wed   grey    100%   
5         1 mon   grey    50%    
6         1 mon   sun     100%   
7         1 wed   cloudy  0%     
8         1 wed   grey    100%
```

If you want to see different combinations, change the variables passed to `group_by` to whatever you want.